# GKE Pods not viewable after cluster downsizes

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I'm [running parallel jobs with expansions](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/parallel-processing-expansion/) on an auto-scaled cluster.  When a pod's node is still running, I can view the pod in the ["Workloads" section of "Kubernetes Engine"](https://console.cloud.google.com/kubernetes/workload).  But if the cluster downsizes due to lack of work, the pods associated the removed nodes disappear from that view (and also from access via CLI `kubectl get pods`).

Is there any way to keep this information from disappearing?  It would be very useful to know the success/failure status, and easily access the logs.

Answer (score 0):

I have found [the document](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/jobs#overview) about running the jobs in GKE and I think you can [inspect the job](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/jobs#inspecting_a_job) with the command `kubectl describe job [JobName]` and observe the events, even after the node is deleted (due to auto scaling)

```
Events:
  Type    Reason            Age   From            Message
  ----    ------            ----  ----            -------
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  16m   job-controller  Created pod: [JobName]-4fkr2
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  16m   job-controller  Created pod: [JobName]-fvr9n
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  16m   job-controller  Created pod: [JobName]-jwjgz
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  16m   job-controller  Created pod: [JobName]-ws4t7
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  16m   job-controller  Created pod: [JobName]-jjjdl
```

the alternative is, if you have enabled the [Stackdriver logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/) i.e. [Stackdriver support for GKE](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/kubernetes-engine/), specially the Stackdriver Kubernetes Engine Monitoring  as [Legacy Stackdriver support is deprecating](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/deprecations/legacy). With below filter[1] in [the advance log queries](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced-queries) you can inspect the logs for the pods under your jobs.

[1]

```
resource.type="container"
resource.labels.cluster_name="[ClusterName]"
resource.labels.namespace_id="[Namespace]"
resource.labels.project_id="[ProjectID]"
resource.labels.zone:"[ZONE]"
resource.labels.container_name="[ContainerName]"
resource.labels.pod_id:"[JobName]-"
```